# Good algorithm for text to code ratio?

Tags: c#, algorithm, html-parsing

In working on a [TextToCodeRatio](http://www.seochat.com/seo-tools/code-to-text-ratio) function for my [SeoTools Excel Plugin](http://nielsbosma.se/projects/seotools), I'd like some input on my approach:

I'm using HtmlAgiltyPack to get all text nodes, discard those that have script and style tags as parent node and perform some additional text manipulation:

```
    public static int CalculateTextSize(HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        int size = 0;
        foreach (HtmlNode node in 
           doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']"))
        {
            HtmlNode parentNode = node.ParentNode;
            if (parentNode != null)
            {
                if (parentNode.Name.Equals("script",
                       StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    || parentNode.Name.Equals("style",
                       StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            string text = node.InnerText.Trim();
            //Just in case agility pack gets it wrong...
            text = StringUtils.StripTags(text);     
            //Replaces "&amp;" => "&" etc.
            text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
            //All whitespace is reduced to single space, i.e. 
            //"Foo\r\nBar\t\   Hello" => "Foo Bar Hello"            
            text = StringUtils.NormalizeWhitespace(text);   
            size += text.Trim().Length;
        }

        return size;
    }
```

What do you think? It's a quite restrictive approach as for example on 
aftonbladet.se my method returns 23722 while the [SeoChat tool](http://www.seochat.com/seo-tools/code-to-text-ratio) returns 28671. Am I doing it wrong?

**UPDATE**: As pointed out by Oskar Kjellin I'm counting chars instead of bytes and SeoChat is counting bytes. What is best, counting chars or bytes? I think that this metric shouldn't be affected by what Encoding the page is written in.

Comment: That doesn't calculate the ratio, just count's the length. And it seem's like he is calculating bytes, you are counting characters

Comment: If you have CalculateTextSize then the rest is trivial. I'm counting chars as I thought this is a better metric. What encoding your're using shouldn't affect text to code ratio?

Comment: But that is of course the reason for the difference... Counting bytes instead I got mine to 2771 (and if I remove HtmlDecode, I get 2979)

Comment: Glad that you found the diff. You should also use the encoding specified in the html. If you use the same encoding for the code, then the ratio won't be affected (probably not so much at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the difference is because he is counting bytes and you are counting character.

I would say that the best is to calculate the bytes as the reason for doing this is to see how many percentage of the loaded page is text. So you have to get the total page size loaded, and use that to calculate. You cannot use character count for that.

Not sure how the search engines do this, but yours is quite easy to fool. You can just put everything inside a big div of text and use CSS to hide the div. It depends on how thorough you want to be.

Comment: I agree, and I'm now using bytes instead. Yes it's easy to fool, but it going to be used to analyze your own site as an on-page metric. Thanks for your input!